# CASE statement using a "tronc"?

Tags: plsql, case, netsuite

My goal is to make a Case statement that says when Bill Credit THEN x when Bill Payment then Y but the field Bill Credit/Payment contain also the reference number in it like Bill Credit #123 so I can't use;

Case {type} when 'Bill Credit' then X ELSE 0 END because there the ref number in it.

Si I'd like something like;

Case when {type} "start with" 'Bill Credit' then X
Same thing for Bill Payment.

Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your complete stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, because `{type}` would not contain any reference numbers, but it sounds like the function you're looking for is `SUBSTR()`

Here's an example of usage"

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTR({field}, 1, 11) = 'Bill Credit' THEN X ELSE 0 END
```

The first argument is the input string, the second is the starting position, and the third is the length of the sub-string to return.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option you might use:

```
SQL> with test (bill) as
  2    (select 'Bill Credit #123' from dual union all
  3     select 'Bill Credit #566' from dual union all
  4     select 'Bill Payment #32' from dual union all
  5     select 'Bill Payment'     from dual
  6    )
  7  select bill,
  8         case when regexp_substr(bill, '\w+', 1, 2) = 'Credit'  then 'X --> credit'
  9              when regexp_substr(bill, '\w+', 1, 2) = 'Payment' then 'Y --> payment'
 10         end result
 11  from test;

BILL             RESULT
---------------- -------------------------
Bill Credit #123 X --> credit
Bill Credit #566 X --> credit
Bill Payment #32 Y --> payment
Bill Payment     Y --> payment

SQL>
```

Depending on what you really have, this code might need to be modified. If you provide test case, it would be easier to assist.